# Proof of stake consensus in non-cryptocurrency blockchains

Tags: blockchain, consensus

I believe the title says it all. There are many proof of stake cryptocurrencies out there (Cardano etc). Also there are many blockchains that are not necessarily tied to some monetary value. Is proof of stake meaningful for such blockchains, since there is no "stake" in the system? Has there been any proposals or research about applying proof of stake consensus to a non-cryptocurrency blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

You need choose some properties and try to define some value that would be accepted by all the members involved, otherwise there is no root for the POS.

Comment: I was thinking sometime similar. Arbitrarily assign some 'stake' value to the participants. If that 'stake' is tied to some other system property that's fine as well. But is there any example of such a thing, either theoretical or actually implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Proof-of-stake consensus requires some stake in the network by definition.

Some private blockchains choose not to offer their tokens for trade and perhaps that is what you mean by a non-cryptocurrency blockchain. POS platforms like Ardor ( [ardorplatform.org](http://ardorplatform.org) ) offer child chains as good solutions for business applications. Projects can also be be easily built with more than a dozen contract features and more than 250 APIs on either NXT ( [nxtplatform.org](http://nxtplatform.org) ) or Ignis - the first child chain of Ardor.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really answer my question. Non-cryptocurrency blockchain = a blockchain that doesn't have monetary value in it. For example: healthcare, property management etc. The question is if PoS can exist in such blockchains (not as a sub-chain of a cryptocurrency)